# how please picture attached above in table HTML

Tags: html

I want my picture below to disguise the above

[image]

and 
and looks like this
[image]

this is my code

```
    <table style="height: 90px; border-top: 5px solid green; line-height: 5px" width="755">
  <tbody>
    {{-- <tr style="height: 10px;"> --}}
      <td style="width: 99px; height: 108px; line-height: 5px"  valign="top" colspan="3">
        <p>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<b>{{ $service->supplier['name'] }}</b>
          <img  src="{{public_path('bcd.png')}}" alt="" class="top" height=100px width=500 align="right"/>
        </p>
```

but not work... what my code wrong ?

Comment: Can you clarify? You want your table to look exactly like the top image is that correct? Also are you adding all your css directly into the HTML?

Comment: i want table lokks like above ,,

Comment: Ok, I would recommend you add all your CSS in a separate CSS file and included it inside the <head></head> tag of your HTML document. Also if you want to get the exact dimensions the image at the top is using, is the image already a website or is it just an image? if it is a website can you add the link? You can check the CSS rules applied to the table using the browsers web inspector.